# Jinja for constructing dictionary in map: [1, 2] into [{'x': 1}, {'x': 2}]

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2

Most Jinja filters are about *reducing* the amount of data.
What if I want to make it bigger?

### Input

A list. The values could be simple, or complex.

```
- 1
- 'a'
- ['b', 'c']
- {'d': 'e'}
```

### Desired Output

I want to produce a list.

- same length as the input list
- Each item in the new list is a dictionary
  with one (key,value) pair.
- The key is hard coded, the same for every item in the output list.
- The value is the corresponding item in the input list.

```
- x: 1
- x: a
- x: ['b', 'c']
- x: {'d': 'e'}
```

What I'm looking for is something like

```
{{ input | map(some_filter, key='x') | list }}
```

What can I use for `some_filter`?

### Notes

I'm using Ansible for this.
So a solution using JMESPath with the `json_query` filter is valid.
Similarly Ansible's a solution using `dict2items` or `items2dict` somehow would also be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ input|json_query('[*].{x: @}') }}"
```

gives

```
  msg:
  - x: 1
  - x: a
  - x:
    - b
    - c
  - x:
      d: e
```

---

[*dict2items*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) is useless here because the input is a list. Also [*items2dict*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-lists-into-dictionaries) is useless here because the result shall be a list too. In addition, [*dict*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest) is also useless because it's not a filter and can't be used in *`map`*. Without *`json_query`* a *`loop`* must be used. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        output: "{{ output + [{'x': item}] }}"
      loop: "{{ input }}"
      vars:
        output: []
```

---

It's possible to write a filter. For example

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/item2dict.py 
def item2dict(t):
    h = {t[0]:t[1]}
    return h

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters. item2dict'''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'item2dict': item2dict
            }
```

Then the task below gives the same result

```yaml
   - debug:
        msg: "{{ 'x'|product(input)|map('item2dict')|list }}"
```